# Как установить глобальный хук на нужное окно?

Tags: c#, hook

Как можно поставить хук только на определённое окно (и ловить информацию только с него) ?!

Comment: Речь идет об одном из окон твоей программы или речь идет о какой-то другой программы?

Comment: И какого рода информацию ты хочешь ловить?

Comment: @iluxa1810, Ловить буду текст, Речь идёт о не моей программе, `не игра`, другое приложение. Вопрос в том как поставить хук именно на нужное мне окно.

Answer (score 4):

Тебе придется воспользоваться WinApi.

1. [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx)- что бы найти нужное окно.
   Если не ошибаюсь, то тоже самое можно получить и так: `Process.GetProcesses()[0].MainWindowHandle`
2. [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx) - что бы найти нужный элемент.
3. [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) - повесить хук

Вот этот [сайт](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html) может помочь с описание этих функций

За основу брал вот [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019790/how-to-find-a-child-of-a-parent-unmanaged-win32-app) вопрос.

Еще есть всякие программы, которые позволяют получить дерево контролов, что бы знать что искать.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользуюсь.